# Why is "the way Trump likes them" put in a list of dishes when it is not a dish?

Tags: meaning-in-context, lists

[Source](http://www.pressreader.com/india/the-times-of-india-mumbai-edition/20160514/282342564061844)

> The Washington Post carefully curated a nine-course meal to document the occasion including newspaper chilaquiles, dumplings, falafel, steaks, **the way Trump likes them**, and even a Trump Tower-inspired taco bowl.

The bold part is not a dish.Then why it is put there?

Edit:The source from where I read it says exactly the same.It wasn't my fault.

Comment: I'm leaving this closed, because it appears that this quote wasn't copied correctly from the [article](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/washington-post-columnist-literally-eats-his-words-on-donald-trump/). It should read _'The Washington Post carefully curated a nine-course meal to document the occasion including newspaper chilaquiles, dumplings, falafel, steaks **("well-done" the way Trump likes them)**, and even a Trump Tower-inspired taco bowl.'_ The punctuation and extra words make the meaning clear.

Comment: You should include your source to confirm the comment above. In fact, I will remind you to always include sources whenever possible.

Comment: Put it there, I wasn't wrong in asking that question.

Comment: Which is why you should always [cite your source](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/976/). The main problem is that the sentence is poorly punctuated. It should be `falafel, steaks (the way Trump likes them), and even...`. Leaving out "well-done" was a bad choice in my opinion because it leaves readers wondering "How does Trump like them?" but it wouldn't make it harder to understand if the punctuation were correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> steaks, **the way Trump likes them**...

You're right, "the way Trump likes them" is not a dish, but it is an explanatory phrase to clarify something else.  The author is specifying that the steaks were prepared in the manner that Trump likes them.  (I don't think this is an example of very good writing, by the way.  It would have been much clearer if the author had written something like "steaks prepared the way Trump likes them".)

> With some of the ink "mercifully **well-ground**" into the steak's chimichurri sauce

**Ground** is the correct word here, not *grounded*.  This is the past participle of [*to grind*](http://en.bab.la/conjugation/english/grind):  Today I grind the spices, yesterday I *ground* the spices.  (*Grounded* would only be correct if the verb were [*to ground*](http://en.bab.la/conjugation/english/ground).)  Again, this does not seem like the best writing to me - ink and chimichurri are both usually liquids, so I don't understand how you would "grind" ink into chimichurri (grinding is something you do to solids) but the meaning is clear enough: it is thoroughly and completely mixed in.

> **To wash it all down**

"It" just refers to the food.  [*To wash something down* is an idiom](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/wash-down) that means "to have drink with your food"; to me it implies that there is a lot of food, so you would need to help it down with some liquid.